# How can I get all values between two variables of type T?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

If I have two variables of type T, would it be possible to get all of the values in between the two variables, assuming that both T types are the same?

I am working in .net 2.0 and have built a Range class based on this code: [Intersection of Date Ranges](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaybaz_ms/archive/2004/08/19/217226.aspx)

If I know that the type is DateTime, it is easy to loop through the dates easily to get to from the Start value to the End value.  Like so:

```
List<DateTime> values = new List<DateTime>();

for (DateTime d = myRange.Start; d <= myRange.End; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    values.Add(d);
}
```

But, to make this more generic, is there a way to do this any type T?

Am I asking for something impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this with an `IComparable<T>`.

```
public static List<T> GetRange(T start, T end, Func<T,T> increment)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    for(T t = start; t.CompareTo(end) < 0; t = increment(t))
    {
        result.Add(t);
    }
    return result;
}

List<DateTime> values = GetRange<DateTime>(myRange.Start, myRange.End, d => d.AddDays(1));
```

The increment function needs to be provided manually for a couple reasons: First, some IComparables don't have a natural increment function: String, for instance. Second, even if there is an increment function, there's no way to find it. Even with your example of DateTimes, there's no way to be sure you wanted `AddDays(1)`, not `AddSeconds(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be impossible to use on any type T.  Not all forms would have a sortable value with distinct steps between them.  An integer from 0-10 is simple.  The same is for your example above.

But how do you get from "boat" to "truck"?  I don't think it can be applied to just any form that easily.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

You can do that but it will only work with types that can be compared in this way.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for cannot be done with generics as implemented in .net.  Your best bet is to define an interface that specifies the operations you need and apply a constraint to `T`.

You could do it with C++ templates for integral values. It would also be trivial in a language that used *duck typing*.

Answer (score 0):

Given that T could be a type that only has one value, I cannot see how this could be solved generically. It may be possible if T supports and interface that allows it's range to be determined.